# Mario The Lost Levels Bonus Levels

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-online, super-mario-bros-the-lost-levels

We have completed the game on Nintendo Switch online but can't seem to get the bonus levels.  We completed level 9 eight times like I read and held down A but nothing happened.
What do we need to do?

Answer (score 4):

You have to beat the whole game eight times to make world A-D accessible

Comment: Does that mean playing the entire game without warp pipes to skip levels, or can you still use warp pipes?

Comment: yes you cant use any warp pipes